# How to add -Ifreetype2 to compiler arguments with CMake?

Tags: include, cmake, mingw

I want to add the compiler flag `-Ifreetype2`. So i did:

```
include_directories( freetype2 )
```

But after running cmake and checking with `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1` nothing is added. What did I wrong?

Comment: `include_directories` should get the job done. You need to provide more detail to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: I created a minimal example: https://gist.github.com/jhasse/7949455
As you can see -Ifreetype2 isn't added to the compiler. I have to admit I don't know much about CMake.

Comment: Which version of CMake are you using? Your example works on my OS X machine with both the `Unix Makefiles` and the `XCode` generator on CMake 2.8.11. Unfortunately I have no MinGW installation ready for testing, but it looks like you have run into a bug in CMake.

Comment: I'm using version 2.8.12.1. Looks like a MinGW related bug then :(

Comment: Ah wait! I've found "-IC:/Users/jhass_000/git/cmaketest/freetype2" inside includes_CXX.rsp. The problem is I need "-IC:/MinGW/include/freetype2" but don't want to hardcode MinGW's path into the CMakeLists.txt. I will look for another solution, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include is inside the file includes_CXX.rsp.